# choroplethr maps in R

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

One more question about choropleth maps is coming . At first lets make some data.

```
`a<-c(4.1,2.5,0.4,6.4,1.4,1.8,3.8,1.3,2.3,8.4,5.2,1.9,0.8,1.5,2.1,1.2,3.8,1.4,3.1,0.8,4.0,1.3,4.8,2.6,2.8,2.3,3.1,2.5)
    target<-c("austria","belgium","bulgaria","switzerland","cyprus","czech republic","denmark",
"estonia","spain","finland","france","greece","croatia","hungary","ireland","italy",
"lithuania","luxembourg","latvia","norway","poland","portugal","romania","sweden",
"slovenia","slovakia","turkey","united kingdom")
datas<-data.frame(region=target,value=a)
datas$region<-as.character(datas$region)
install.packages("choroplethr")
install.packages("choroplethrMaps")
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
data(country.map)
data(country.regions)


 gg <- country_choropleth(datas,legend="%",num_colors=1,zoom=target)
gg <- gg + xlim(-31.266001, 39.869301)
gg <- gg + ylim(27.636311, 81.008797)
gg <- gg + coord_map("lambert", lat0=27.636311, lat1=81.008797)
gg`
```

So the output is [image]

The thing that i cant adjust is to leave a country uncolored . If i set a country's value equal to 0 , that would drastically change the scale of the colors for the others. My target is to add countries that i don't have data for in the map and set their color to grey to make the map more realistic and to point out the countries that i have data for .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that there are two things here.

1. By default, all NA values in choroplethr are rendered as black:

   ```
   a <- c(NA, NA, NA,6.4,1.4,1.8,3.8,1.3,2.3,8.4,
          5.2,1.9,0.8,1.5,2.1,1.2,3.8,1.4,3.1,0.8,
          4.0, 1.3,4.8,2.6,2.8,2.3,3.1,2.5)
   ...
   ```

[image: default na]

2. Note that you can override the scale by this:

   ```
   gg + scale_fill_continuous(low="#eff3ff", high="#084594", na.value="yellow")
   ```

[image: custom-scale]

You said that you wanted the NA values to appear grey. You can do that too just by changing the value of the `na.value`. Here I chose yellow just for a large contrast because this is an example.

Comment: Thanks man . I had already tried to set the values i want to NA but without   the scale_fill_continous  it ruined the result because it added the black color scale.  Beautiful

Comment: One more question just came up . Is there any way to paint with black let's say the perimeter of each country in order to make them more distinguishable?

Comment: Can you ask that as a separate question? Something like "How to change the border of a choroplethr country map?"